# How to capture SOAP messages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have configured TCP/IP monitor on my eclipse by following the steps given in [How to trace SOAP message in Eclipse IDE](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-trace-soap-message-in-eclipse-ide/), but when I execute my client code then the TCP is monitoring only the wsdl URL's not my client request to the service.

[image]

In the above image, I am making request to `sayHello` on my webservice but the TCP monitor is showing the request to wsdl. I want to see the SOAP request and response messages in my eclipse. How can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens:

a) The Client sends a request for the wsdl. You see this request in the TCP/IP monitor.
b) The endpoint sends the wsdl. It contains a

```
<soap:address location="...."></soap:address>
```

pointing to the real endpoint address.

c) The client sends the soap request using this address, bypassing the TCP/IP monitor.

As a workaround, you need to override the address specified in the WSDL with the monitor address:

```
HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class)
((BindingProvider)hello).getRequestContext()
   .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"http://localhost:8081/HelloWorldSoapWS/hello");
hello.sayHello("...");
```

What a mess.